# Nomogram with R

Tags: r

[image: Mydata]

```
view("Mydata")
summary(Mydata)
dim(Mydata)
x = as.matrix(Mydata[,-c(1,2)])
str(x)
time = Mydata$DFT
#time <- as.numeric(time)
event = Mydata$Rec
library(survival)
y = Surv(time, event)
suppressMessages(library(doParallel))
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
aenetfit = fit_aenet(x, y, nfolds = 10, rule = "lambda.1se",
                       seed = c(5, 7), parallel = TRUE)

names(aenetfit)
fit = aenetfit$model_init
alpha = aenetfit$alpha_init
lambda = aenetfit$lambda_init
adapen = aenetfit$pen_factor
suppressMessages(library("rms"))
x.df = as.data.frame(x)
dd = datadist(x.df)
options(datadist = "dd")

nom <- as_nomogram(aenetfit, x, time, event, pred.at = 365 * 2,
                   funlabel = "2-Year Overall Survival Probability")
plot(nom)
```

---

1. I intend to create a nomogram. I have used my own data named
   "Mydata".
2. It has 9 columns (the time to event column is DFT, while the output of interest is Rec which is binary).

When I run the code, everything worked except the plot (nom). It gave the below error.

Thank you.

[image: Error message from plot (nom)]

Comment: Yes. I have edited the questions. To answer you, I have my own data separately. It is called Mydata. It has 9 columns (where the time to event column was Dtime and the output column of interest was Recurrence). The above is my code.

Comment: Yes. With the smart data, it worked fine. However, with my own data. I was having an issue. As you have suggested, I will screenshot a section of my data. Thank you for trying to help out. I really appreciate the time and efforts.

Comment: @ Ben. Please, can I send the first 20 rows to you personally? Cos, I can only send a printscreen of the picture here. Thank you.

Comment: @ Ben. Thanks for your readiness to assist. It is a sensitive data. I have edited the data and renamed the variables. I tried with the attached data, the error was the same. It gives the same error as when I tried with the entire dataset. I have manually checked the data, there was no missing values or NaN. I uploaded the data as excel document in R studio. Should I have used CSV file? Could it because of the commas in the columns.

Comment: @ Ben. Thanks. Maybe I am missing something. Strange that it worked well for you. I forgot to mention that the DFT column is in months. The highest value for the DFT column is 267 months. Before I out the question on Stackoverflow, I had tried using five years prediction (365 * 5) and (365 * 7), both gave the same error as screenshot above.

Comment: @ Ben. I changed it to pred. at = 12 * 2. Using this, I got a nomogram.

Comment: @ Ben. I changed it to pred. at = 12 * 2. Using this, I got a nomogram. If this is the right approach, I will mark one of your comments as the answer as you have technically answered the question. However, I have another concern. I noticed that the approach is that, my input parameters (columns) were reduced from 16 columns to 6 columns in the plotted nomogram. However, I will like to develop the nomogram with another 6 columns (evidence-based variables) and I don't want that the function reduces input variables. I don't want that the function reduces my input parameters. How can I do that?

Comment: If you'd like, you can provide an answer to your own question. With regards to parameters in the nomogram, I would create a separate question, and use `dput()` to share your example data. If this is a modeling issue (more than a programming issue), you might want to consider stack exchange Cross Validated to get more statistical support.